# NSTextField selectable is not working. Does anyone know what's going on?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I place two labels in table view cell. I want label enable select feature. And set the Behavior property is `Selectable`, but not working. Does anyone know what's going on?

- [Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM8MT.png)
- [Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHDuH.png)
- [Label Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hN4k.png)

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue? Post a [mre] please.

Comment: I know what's causing it. I implementation  the `tableView(_:shouldSelectRow:)` func and return false. But I didn't want table view cell selection style, what should I do?

Comment: I solved. 1. remove the `tableView(_:shouldSelectRow:)` func. 2. Disable the table view's selection style by `tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .none`. Thank you @Willeke

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

1. remove the `tableView(_:shouldSelectRow:)` func.
2. Disable the table view's selection style by `tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .none`.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried `Selectable` so I am not sure of how it works. However, I think what you're trying to do is what Picker View does. An [`UIPickerView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview?language=objc) lets you select one
text element among several others.

Comment: Please explain how `UIPickerView` can replace `NSTextField.isSelectable`.